# Working with Windows Server Media Foundation from within a containerized application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2012-r2, ms-media-foundation, windows-api-code-pack

I am utilizing [Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) (version 1.1.0) and [Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Core/) (version 1.1.0) for reading metadata of audio & video files (specifically duration). So far, this solution was working perfectly fine, deployed on Windows Server 2012 and above, with the Windows Server Media Foundation feature enabled. However, recently the hosting of the application has moved to containers (i.e. Docker), instead of standard Windows Server.

Due to that fact, the Windows Server Media Foundation was no longer available by default and so my implementation has stopped working. The administrators of the containers have required from me to bundle all of the necessary dependencies into the application itself and then ship it over for deployment.

The issue is that I am not aware what exactly does the WindowsAPICodePack-Shell utilize on the backend, so that I can include all of the necessary dependencies for it. My guess is that it relies on lower-level (C/C++) libraries, which pre-populate files' metadata and then that data could be read via the WindowsAPICodePack.

Is there a way to include the corresponding dependencies for the WindowsAPICodePack, so that it could be utilized safely, no matter if Windows Server Media Foundation is available or not?